# Add Math function to SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

New to SQL and I am trying to run a query that pulls all our item codes, lot number, and qty on hand.

Each lot number has multiple entries due to adjustments. I need a way of running my query and having it add or subtract to get the actual qty on hand for each lot and only show me lots that are in the negatives. I have tried playing with SSRS but I cant get it right. I'm using SQL 2008R2.

```
SELECT
  IMLAYER.ITEM_CODE
 ,IMMSTR.ITEM_DESC
 ,IMLAYER.LOT_NO
 ,IMLAYER.QTY_ON_HAND
FROM
  IMLAYER
INNER JOIN
  IMMSTR
    ON
    IMLAYER.ITEM_CODE = IMMSTR.ITEM_CODE
WHERE
  (IMLAYER.QTY_ON_HAND < 0);
```

Comment: Hello, we need expected result and samples of data. But i think you can find some solution with the GROUP BY clause and aggregation function like `SUM()`.

Comment: Your question is not clear what you are trying to do. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to get ideas. Also we need some sample data and such. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for what you should post.

Comment: So you want to SUM all of the QTY_ON_HAND, but then only return the records where the SUM is negative? I assume this is for an inventory replenishment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand the requirements correctly, but if not please comment and I can update the query:

```
SELECT
    M.ITEM_CODE
   ,M.ITEM_DESC
   ,L.LOT_NO
   ,'SUM_OF_QTY_ON_HAND' = SUM(L.QTY_ON_HAND)
FROM
    IMLAYER L
INNER JOIN
    IMMSTR M
    ON L.ITEM_CODE = M.ITEM_CODE
GROUP BY
    M.ITEM_CODE
    ,M.ITEM_DESC
    ,L.LOT_NO
HAVING
    SUM(L.QTY_ON_HAND) < 0
```

`HAVING` is the trick you are looking for to be able to use an aggregate function for filtering.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I couldn't explain it better but your solution worked perfect.

Comment: No problem. I come from background in accounting/ERP software so I am familiar with this type of project.